# Iterating and updating through feature class fields based on DataFrame using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, features, iteration, data-frame

I am updating mismatched data across two systems and have an Excel sheet that combines a consolidated data set. Unfortunately I do not have a reliable join field to relate this back to my GIS data.

I have brought in the corrected data as a Pandas DataFrame and was hoping to iterate through each feature in my GIS layer. If there was a join attribute I would then update the fields in the GIS as required. However if there was not a join on the field (e.g. the field was empty, didn't match, or was duplicated) then I wanted to create a list of records I could then interrogate further.

Is there an ArcPy method to select a layer and then iterate through each feature and then each field. I am relatively new to ArcPy and think I am looking up the wrong terms.

Comment: Can you add a concrete example of want you want to do? For example using screenshots

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [da.SearchCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm)

> SearchCursor establishes read-only access to the records returned from
> a feature class or table.
>
> It returns an iterator of tuples. The order of values in the tuple
> matches the order of fields specified by the field_names argument.

And [da.UpdateCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) if you want to update/change values.